# How to parse textfile correctly?

Tags: c, file, parsing, pointers, printing

I've got a text file containing a bunch of random data from programs I've written:

```
hdfs45 //the hdsf part stays the same everytime, but the number always changes
```

I'm trying to parse this line of data into two parts, the `hdfs` part and the `45` part (to be later converted to an int)

I've tried something along the lines of this:

```
Char * a, * b;
char str[100];
FILE* ptr;

ptr = fopen("test.txt","r"); // opens sucessfully

while(fgets(str,100,file))
{
    a = strtok(str," \n");
    printf("%s",a); // but this prints the whole string

}
```

The data will be random, for setting the delimiter to "45" is useless. However the first part "hdfs" is always the same,any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you want to do, that is a very specific example, a generic way would be difficult to suggest.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that there is only one set of characters and one set of numbers? If so, then I suggest looking into [`isdigit`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/)

Comment: The hdfs part never changes, but the number after it always does.

Comment: If the prefix is always the same, `strncmp(str, "hdfs", 4)`, just to be sure and then `atoi(str + 4)` (or an equivalent call to `strtol`.) If the prefix is variable, you can use `strpbrk` to find the first digt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "hdfs" never changes, then you can simply convert the characters after the first 4 into a number, i.e.:

```
int num = atoi(str + 4);
str[4] = '\0';
```

In your example, `num` will equal `45`, and `str` will equal `hdfs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `strtok` because there is nothing to tokenize (you can't use a delimiter), try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[100] = "hdfs45";
    char *ptr;
    long num;

    ptr = strpbrk(str, "012345679");
    if (ptr) {
        num = strtol(ptr, NULL, 10);
        *ptr = '\0';
        printf("%s -> %ld\n", str, num);
    }
    return 0;
}
```